# Invalid IL code in System.Drawing.ColorConverter:.ctor (): method body is empty

Tags: asp.net

初めまして。私は、ヴィジュアルスタジオ2012、リナックスサーバで、ウエブサイトを開発していたのですが、サーバにアップしたところ、上記のようなエラーが出てしまい、トップページから、他のページに移動出来なくなってしまいました。今までは、ページ移動も、出来ていました。
System.Drawingと、System.Drawing.Designを、削除し、再参照してみても、ダメでした。
どなたか解決策をご存知の方教えて下さい。

Server Error in '/' Application

Invalid IL code in System.Drawing.ColorConverter:.ctor (): method body is empty.

Description: HTTP 500. Error processing request.

Stack Trace:

System.InvalidProgramException: Invalid IL code in System.Drawing.ColorConverter:.ctor (): method body is empty.

at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0

Comment: 開発に使った環境と、アップした先のサーバの環境、それぞれをもう少し詳しく書いてみてはどうでしょうか? VS2012と書かれていることから、開発時はWindowsを使っていたが、運用サーバはLinuxだったのかなと推測できますが、正確な情報が必要でしょう。

Comment: 問題となっている箇所のソースコードを提示すると回答者の助けになると思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。環境は、Windowsで、運用サーバは、Linuxです。問題となっている箇所が特定出来なく、全てのソースコードを載せられないので、困っています。

Comment: @ComMk 自分が全部の情報（環境の詳細、ソースコード、問題の現象）があるため、問題を特定するには自分でできなかったら、質問の情報だけで問題を定義するだけでも難しいです。できれば、もう一回問題を自分で分析した上、関連なコードや問題の原因を把握できれば、回答しやすくなると思います。最小限の情報がなかったら、回答はできないと思います。

Answer (score 1):

情報が少ないので想像になりますが、
VS2012で使っている.net frameworkのバージョンと、Linuxで動いているMonoの互換の問題のように見えます。双方の互換を確認してみてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。.net frameworkのバージョンと、Linuxで動いているMonoの互換は、問題ないみたいです。少ない情報で、すいません。互換に問題があっても、トップページは見れるのでしょうか？トップページだけがキチンと見れるのが不思議です。

Answer (score 0):

[この回答](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21166151/invalid-il-code-system-io-compression-zipfile-openread-method-body-is-empty)が役に立つかもしれません。
「Invalid IL code in　（）method body is empty」
という形式を持っているようです。
これを訳すと
「（）メソッド本体の無効なILコードは空です」
となりました。
憶測ですが、
ヘッダファイルのみあり本体ファイルやDLLが見当たらないためにエラーが起きているのだと思います。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。「この回答」を確認してみたところ、As soon as I referenced the System.IO.Compression from C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\Framework it worked　の部分で、なんかバージョンを変更したら、治った的な回答みたいです。
メソッド本体については、ヴィジュアルスタジオの、オブジェクトブラウザーでしか、確認してませんが、System.Drawing.ColorConverterの中身は、入ってるみたいです。
ローカルにも、DLLが入ってます。
ちなみに、「この回答」にﾘﾝｸを張るのは、どのようにすればいいのですか？

Comment: リンクはマークダウン記法が使えます。コメント追加を行う際、入力欄の右にある`ヘルプ`を押すと具体的な記法も表示されます。

Comment: わかりました。ありがとうございます。